# Using ggplot2 to plot geom_errorbar for Date in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

In many cases, we need to demonstrate the standard error. In `ggplot2`, we can do it using the `geom_errorbar` function. I find that when the x variable is of the Date type, ggplot2 could not plot the error bar completely. See the R script below for more information.

```
library(gcookbook) # For the data set
# Take a subset of the cabbage_exp data for this example
ce <- subset(cabbage_exp, Cultivar == "c39")
# With a line graph

p1 = ggplot(ce, aes(x=Date, y=Weight)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Weight-se, ymax=Weight+se), width=.2)

ce$Date = as.Date(c('01/01/2001', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2003'), "%m/%d/%Y") 

p2 = ggplot(ce, aes(x=Date, y=Weight)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Weight-se, ymax=Weight+se), width=.2)

p1
p2
```

[image]

Comment: I still see errorbars, only the horizontal line at the end is missing. That's because the width of one day is to small to be seen. Try `width=10`

Comment: @RHA is right. To get the same relative width of the errorbars (20% of distance between data points - if equidistantly distributed), try: `width=.2 * ((max(ce$Date)-min(ce$Date))/length(ce$Date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply following [RHA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4611308/rha)'s [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981813/using-ggplot2-to-plot-geom-errorbar-for-date-in-r#comment55721321_33981813) (code below). @RHA, please feel free to copy my answer into a new one as it's more yours then it's mine.

[image: geom_errorbar of width]

```
# install.packages("gcookbook", dependencies = TRUE)
library(gcookbook) # For the data set
# Take a subset of the cabbage_exp data for this example
ce <- subset(cabbage_exp, Cultivar == "c39")
# With a line graph

# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)

ce$Date = as.Date(c('01/01/2001', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2003'), "%m/%d/%Y") 

(p2 = ggplot(ce, aes(x=Date, y=Weight)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Weight- se, ymax= Weight + se), width=45)))
```